# robotframework ride:Chinese character displayed error in the result area

Tags: robotframework-ide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cWAl.png)

My Environment is windows10x64,python3,robotfranework3.1.1,rf-ride1.7.3
Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: This is a known problem in Windows. Only a code fix in RIDE will correct the characters. There no problem with test execution or results.